# Which faces do Ivy/Counsel use in the minibuffer?

Tags: faces, minibuffer, ivy

Which faces are being applied to the indicated text, i.e. the strings `3114`, `M-x`, and `C-x C-c`, in the following screenshot?

[image: Minibuffer screenshot]

I am using the packages Ivy and Counsel, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: When we are *not* dealing with `Ivy` or `Counsel`, the normal faces are `default` and `minibuffer-prompt`.  I do not use either library, so I have no idea whether different faces are being used.  You may wish to start with those two faces and see if that does the trick.  In terms of people who down-vote without leaving a comment, if it were up to me, I would forbid down-voting without leaving a constructive comment and identifying oneself so the whole world can see who disapproves.  But, I'm not in charge -- sometimes, I just leave a comment admonishing people to leave a constructive comment.

Comment: Probably C-u C-x =  (C-u M-x what-cursor-position) give you the answer

Comment: When asking this sort of question, please specify the keys/commands you invoked as accurately as possible. One would have to be quite familiar with Counsel to guess that they are looking at a `counsel-M-x` completion session, and even then that is only an educated guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the minibuffer contents shown are the result of the command `counsel-M-x`, which is intended as an enhanced version of `execute-extended-command`, then:

- `3114 M-x` is propertised with the `minibuffer-prompt` face, as lawlist correctly guessed in [a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41137/does-anyone-know-what-the-minibuffer-font-faces-are-called#comment64601_41137).
- `C-x C-c` (excluding surrounding parentheses) is propertised with the `font-lock-keyword-face` face by the function [`counsel-M-x-transformer`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/cd2aab02dd646daf544613d76e4adb3eef462cea/counsel.el#L761-L768).